# An upgrade from 'hirsute' to 'jammy' is not supported with this tool

Tags: upgrade, ubuntu-22.04, ubuntu-21.04

i was upgrading ubuntu 21.04 hirsute to 22.04 by following this tutorial ,in step 6 it's failing it's throwing an following error please help me to fix this issue

```
Reading cache

Checking package manager

Can not upgrade 

An upgrade from 'hirsute' to 'jammy' is not supported with this tool.
```

```
https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-upgrade-ubuntu-to-22-04-lts-jammy-jellyfish
```

Answer (score 18):

UPDATE: thanks to smknstd, JoeCool, MDarrinT and PurplProto.

Script is working again.

You can chose 3 different methods:

```
# First method, upgrade to 22.04 with the official ubuntu method ( old-releases.ubuntu.com )
# Replace sources.list   
text="deb http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ hirsute main restricted universe multiverse
deb http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ hirsute-updates main restricted universe multiverse
deb http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ hirsute-security main restricted universe multiverse"
sudo echo "$text" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list
# Prerequisites
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install update-manager-core update-manager -y
sudo apt-get upgrade -y
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade -y 
# Download and run the ubuntu upgrade tool
wget http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/jammy-updates/main/dist-upgrader-all/current/jammy.tar.gz
tar -xaf jammy.tar.gz 
sudo ./jammy --frontend=DistUpgradeViewText

-------------------------------++++++++++++++++++++++++--------------------------------

# Second method, upgrade to 22.04 replacing the entire sources.list with the jammy repos
# Replace sources.list   
text="deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ jammy main universe restricted multiverse
deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ jammy main universe restricted multiverse
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security main universe restricted multiverse
deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security main universe restricted multiverse
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ jammy-updates main universe restricted multiverse
deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ jammy-updates main universe restricted multiverse"
sudo echo "$text" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list
# Bypass "An upgrade from 'xxx' to 'xxx' is not supported with this tool" error
sudo sed -i 's/continue/pass/g' /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/UpdateManager/Core/MetaRelease.py
# Start upgrade
sudo apt-get update
sudo do-release-upgrade
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade -y
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade -y
sudo apt-get install -f -y
sudo apt-get autoremove --purge -y
       
-------------------------------++++++++++++++++++++++++--------------------------------

# Third method, upgrade to 22.04 replacing the current distro codename with jammy into the sources.list with sed
# Replace sources.list  
sudo sed -i 's/hirsute/jammy/g' /etc/apt/sources.list
# Bypass "An upgrade from 'xxx' to 'xxx' is not supported with this tool" error
sudo sed -i 's/continue/pass/g' /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/UpdateManager/Core/MetaRelease.py
# Start upgrade
sudo apt-get update
sudo do-release-upgrade
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade -y
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade -y
sudo apt-get install -f -y
sudo apt-get autoremove --purge -y
```

LInk to the complete github script [here](https://github.com/daboynb/linux_scripts/blob/main/upgrade_eol_to_jammy.sh).

Comment: This just upgrades you from 21.04 to 21.10… do you have to do this and then run it again to update from 21.10 to 22.04?

Comment: yes two times, tested yesterday on a vm. 21.04 to 21.10 and then 21.10 to 22.04

Comment: it worked for me, but before I had to edit the source list to point to the "old releases" endpoint: 
`sed -i.bak -r 's/(archive|security).ubuntu.com/old-releases.ubuntu.com/g' /etc/apt/sources.list`

Comment: I getting WARNING:root:file 'impish.tar.gz.gpg' missing How i have to workaround that?

Comment: Try the new script

Comment: I used the script above, but it does not help

Comment: If you used the "sed -i.bak -r 's/(archive|security).ubuntu.com/old-releases.ubuntu.com/g'" command you will be unable to use that script. 
Use the second one instead https://github.com/daboynb/linux_scripts/blob/main/upgrade_eol_to_jammy.sh.

Comment: Thank you, script worked! 21.10 today to 22.04

Answer (score 7):

Well, I tried the approach above. It failed.

Going through the script, I decided to check the Ubuntu server for the packages. Strange, there are all these `NotFound` errors. Guess what? The apt files referenced were missing from the Ubuntu server.

Then I went in and changed all the `hirsute` labels to `jammy` in the `/etc/apt/sources.list` file. Once I did that, *apt* ran. I could then run the script indicated above and have it find the packages.

Now, it works. A couple of messages about *php-fpm* not being enabled under *Apache HTTP*, but since I run *nginx*, I hope it works.

And it worked. I had to run through the `apt upgrade && apt update && apt dist-upgrade && apt autoremove` to clean out the detritus, but I have a working install on LTS.

Comment: You can use `sed` to make updating the sources list easier: `sed -i 's/hirsute/jammy/g' /etc/apt/sources.list`.

Answer (score 2):

Before running the script, I had to modify my sources.list (/etc/apt/sources.list) and comment-out all lines leaving only these:

```
## EOL upgrade sources.list
# Required
deb http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ jammy main restricted universe multiverse
deb http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ jammy-updates main restricted universe multiverse
deb http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ jammy-security main restricted universe multiverse
deb http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ jammy-backports main restricted universe multiverse
```

Then it went first to 'impish' and then to 'jammy' by running the script twice.

Or you can `sudo do-release-upgrade` after the first script; from 'impish' to 'jammy'.

Thank you and voted-up your answer.

Comment: @PurplProto I'm not so to linux yet, but hope I will use sed next time.

Answer (score -1):

official (unsupported) upgrade path from EOL is described here:

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EOLUpgrades

and requires pointing apt to old-releases.ubuntu.com mirror

Comment: An upgrade from 'hirsute' to 'jammy' is not supported with this tool. And "impish" version goes to 404